# T-SQL Query to fill dropdown with available dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My Scenario: I have a website which have event calendar & a booking form for visitor to book their visit let us say some garden xyz. When an event is taking place in this garden then visitors are not allowed to visit the garden.

Event Calender is maintained by the Management and if the event is taking place from 2012-06-16 Till 2012-06-20 & for this event they close the garden for any visitor.

on the other side on the booking for i have to show available dates for visitors in a dropdown or some popup calender which will block dates booked in an event calender.

**Event Data is stored in Event_Calender Table which has fields like**

```
Event_ID
Event_Name
Event_Start_Date
Event_End_Date
Event_Start_Time
Event_End_Time
Event_Block_Visitor
```

Important On any Day only 50 Visitor are allowed to visit the Garden
**And Visitor Data is store in Visitor_Booking Table Table structure**

```
Booking_ID
Booking_Date
Visitor_Name
No_Of_Visitor
EMail_ID
Contact_No
```

Booking Form has a dropdown which should show available dates Based one

1. Dates which are not booked or blocked in the event calender
2. If June 28 already made booking for 50 Visitor then June 28 should not show up in the available booking date table.

My Table structure is bit complex then show on the example.

I would appreciate if someone can do this in a best way.

I am trying to generate `Booked_Dates` from `Event_Calender Table` using one query & With Other Query i am trying to generate booked Dates with 50 booking from `Visitor_Booking` Table.

This will give me all dates that are booked. Now i have the date which are blocked based on this how can i generate dates which are available for visits.

**CTE query to generate Booked date from even calendar**

**NOTE: One issue with the query result has been Result that was related to the query fetching results older than specified dates. it was due to operator precedence**

[image: RESULT]

Script so far:

```
;WITH Calendar
     AS (SELECT EventID,
                EventTitle,
                EventStartDate,
                EventEndDate,
                EventEnumDays,
                EventRecurring,
                EventStartTime,
                EventEndTime,
                EventStartDate AS PlannedDate,
                EventType,
                EventCategory
         FROM   EventCalender
         WHERE  EventActive = 1
                AND LanguageID = 1
                AND EventBlockDate = 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT EventID,
                EventTitle,
                EventStartDate,
                EventEndDate,
                EventEnumDays,
                EventRecurring,
                EventStartTime,
                EventEndTime,
                Dateadd(dd, 1, PlannedDate),
                EventType,
                EventCategory
         FROM   Calendar
         WHERE  EventRecurring = 1
                AND Dateadd(dd, 1, PlannedDate) <= EventEndDate)
SELECT EventID,
       EventStartDate,
       EventEndDate,
       PlannedDate AS [EventDates],
       EventStartTime,
       EventEndTime,
       Cast(EventStartDate AS DATETIME) + '' + Cast(EventStartTime AS DATETIME) AS DT,
       EventTitle,
       EventType,
       EventCategory,
       Datename(weekday, PlannedDate) AS [WEEKDAY],
       Getdate() AS [YYYY/MM/DD]
FROM   Calendar
WHERE  PlannedDate >= Getdate()
       AND ',' + EventEnumDays + ',' LIKE '%,' + Cast(Datepart(dw, PlannedDate) AS CHAR(1)) + ',%'
        OR EventEnumDays IS NULL
ORDER  BY EventID,
          PlannedDate
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: I completed the Event Calender integration with Full Calender, so that i can generate booked dates from Event_Calender. I am looking for ideas for implementing as i want to generate dates using sql query rather than writing some logic in C# based on the dates already booked. I will add and image that show my CTE query even that is giving me little undesired result as it is also showing me results of dates which are less the the specified date in where clause.. I will add image in a moment to my quetsion.

Comment: put your query in the question so that other can suggest you to improve the query or error in it..

Comment: query is also part of question

Comment: What data-type is `PlannedDate`? Also, you are filtering on `PlannedDate`, but showing us `EventDates`. Where is the `PlannedDate` that is unexpected?

Comment: PlannedDate as [EventDates] is Column Alias and it show all dates between EventStartDate & EventEndDate. With this PlannedDate as [EventDates] i get all the dates that are blocked.

Comment: `PlannedDate as [EventDates]` in CTE query also shows only recurring days of date

Comment: EventEnumDays is not included your sample data. Have you verified it's not null?

Comment: One issue with your current query is that `AND` has [higher precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) than `OR`, so that's why you're seeing results from an earlier date.

Comment: Seraphym: I store `EventEnumDays` as 1,3,5 & So on. that part is working fine

Comment: Damien: Resolved the issue of precedence by `where (PlannedDate >= '2012-06-01') AND.....` & now i have correct result. Thanks for hinting correctly to resolve one part of problem..

Comment: It's recommended to use [Datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) for date comparison logic.  It will help ensure that you are comparing the correct parts of the dates - in your case, excluding any time parts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get dates for which the garden is booked for an event
2. Get dates for which the garden has reached full visit capacity (==50)
3. combine 1 and 2 results
4. Choose a calender to display/choose booking/visiting date
5. On the Load/month change event of calender, somehow disable the dates recieved in step 3

see this sample code:

```
   static List<DateTime> lstBookedDates;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            lstBookedDates = new List<DateTime>();
            lstBookedDates.Add(DateTime.Today);
            lstBookedDates.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(2));
            lstBookedDates.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2));
            lstBookedDates.Add(DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1));
            lstBookedDates.Add(DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1).AddDays(2));
        }
    }

    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstBookedDates.Where(a=> e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString().Equals(a.Date.ToShortDateString())).Count()>0)
        {
            foreach (Control c in e.Cell.Controls)
            {
                if (typeof(LiteralControl) == c.GetType())
                {

                    LiteralControl c1 = (LiteralControl)c;
                    c1.Text = "";
                }
            }
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            e.Cell.ToolTip = "Booking full";
            e.Cell.Enabled = false;

        }        
    }
```